# Did Ares bring Wonder Woman to him or did she accidentally stumble onto his location?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman, wonder-woman-2017

**Major spoilers ahead!**

In the 2017 *Wonder Woman*, Diana is in Themyscira and Ares is initially in London, which given his role there, seems to be a permanent residence.

We learn that Ares can teleport and has been influencing people like Isabel Maru, but doesn’t go to Themyscira.

As best I can tell, the sequence of events goes as follows:

1. Steve Trevor goes on his mission (Did Ares influence this?)
2. Steve is discovered and makes a hasty escape on a plane
3. Steve gets shot down right as he approaches Themyscira
4. Steve barely survives the crash into the sea thanks to Diana being on the nearby cliffs
5. The Germans arrive at Themyscira and are defeated, with Steve narrowly avoiding several bullets
6. The Amazons decide not to kill Steve outright and allow him to leave
7. Diana decides to join Steve on his journey, despite the other Amazons' protests
8. They arrive in London, where it turns out Ares has been hanging out for long enough to have an established role as Sir Patrick Morgan

Did Ares somehow influence events such that Steve getting shot down, Diana rescuing him, and all the other steps in such a way that they were entirely part of his plan to draw her to him? Or did Diana get the luckiest break ever by blindly stumbling onto Ares’ permanent residence?

Comment: Can we really answer this?

Comment: is there **any** indication that Area knew of Themyscira? I thought it was hidden. I doubt it or he would have just destroyed it.

Comment: Why would Ares attract Diana to him? Without her intervention, he would have destroyed mankind.

Comment: For the same reason he doesn't instantly attempt to destroy her when he first realises who she is (while she is ignorant of who he is) - because they're they last of their kind (that they know of), and he wants to win her over and have her join him.

Comment: @Paulie_D Correct, I mean Germans. I've fixed my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost, Themyscira is designed to be hidden from Ares. It's almost the sole purpose of the place. If he had known where it was he could have done something about it long ago.

Ares own description of how he has been working is that of 'whispering in selective ears' - in other words he hasn't been using grand supernatural powers to create the war, just little nudges to the way humans are already thinking. The grand supernatural powers, he implies, aren't necessary.

It would imply more control than he describes himself as using to arrange for Steve to crash precisely on Themyscira, even if he had known where it was. Ares also seems to exhibit a certain amount of surprise at seeing Diana in London.

Given how much he tells Diana about what he has been doing towards the end of the movie, it seems unlikely that he would *not* have told her about his grand plan to bring her from Themyscira if there had been one (and out of universe the writers would very likely have used that opportunity to tell the audience about the grand plan if there had been one).

We can reasonably conclude that Diana's arrival in London is unplanned by Ares. That doesn't mean he doesn't manipulate her after that of course. And given that nothing is said definitively, this answer is not immune to retconning.

Comment: I think the fact that Ares didn't gloat about bringing Diana to London is the strongest evidence for me that he didn't. Thanks for the great answer!